# How to return list of all values that have matching first 4 characters

Tags: python, excel, excel-formula

I have a large list of product ID's setup up in the following format;

```
SKU
1002NAV
1003BLU
1007PNB
1008NAV
1009NAV
1010BLK
1010BLU
1011BLU
1011BUR
1011GRY
1011NAV
```

The first 4 numbers representing the style of product and corresponding 3 letters representing the colour, as a result any products that have the same 4 number style ID will be identical products (just different colours)

I would like to return a list of all full product ID's that have multiple styles in order to group them, so the above list would return something like;

```
SKU
1010BLK
1010BLU
1011BLU
1011BUR
1011GRY
1011NAV
```

It would ignore the other SKU's such as `1002NAV` as there is only one style of this product.

I have a little knowledge of python as well if this cannot be done in excel but would prefer to keep it all within excel if possible.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you trying to accomplish this using Excel Formulas or Python? Can you confirm? With excel formulas you can do this `=LET(_sku,LEFT(A2:A12,4),
_distinctsku,UNIQUE(_sku,,1),
_tr,TRANSPOSE(_distinctsku),
_counter,SEQUENCE(COUNTA(_distinctsku),,1,0),
FILTER(A2:A12,MMULT(--(_tr=_sku),_counter^0)=0))`

Comment: Or `=LET(a,A2:A12,FILTER(a,MMULT(--(TRANSPOSE(LEFT(a,4))=(LEFT(a,4))),ROW(a)^0)>1))` or `=LET(a,A2:A12,FILTER(a,DROP(FREQUENCY(--(LEFT(a,4)),--(LEFT(a,4))),-1)<>1))`

Comment: Or, `=TOCOL(MAP(A2:A12,LAMBDA(m,IF(COUNTIF(A2:A12,UNIQUE(LEFT(m,4))&"*")>1,m,NA()))),3)`

Comment: Thank you, sorry I wasnt clear. I want to accomplish with excel formula's, but I know it is a little limited so if it wasn't possible I would have been comfortable trying a solution using python as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your input is a list of unique SKU's, try:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=FILTER(A1:A11,COUNTIF(A1:A11,LEFT(A1:A11,4)&"*")>1,"")
```

Comment: thank you, but this seems to still be returning values that only have one colour of the style, see [screenshot](https://gyazo.com/aef6028df038323ade0ffb4ea0a16ad5) returning ID MWC337NAV when there is only one colour of MWC337, it should ignore this?

Comment: Ignore above, I think I found issue. I need to change formula to use first 6 characters for these SKU's not 4! Thank you for your help!